# How do I add custom dropdowns in Command Bar in sharepoint modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-designer, spfx, spfx-extensions

I am trying to add some of the previous ribbon functionality in the command bar for modern sharepoint UI and stack all of them in separate dropdowns.

Any feasible solution will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Mega menu and you should reach it if you click on cog wheel on your site collection and then "change the look" and then "Header".

Comment: Just in case OP need reference link for mega menu: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Organize-your-SharePoint-sites-with-megamenu-navigation-and-new/ba-p/328068